# Date and Time fields combine to DateTime in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have 2 fields, Date and Time, which need to be combined into 1 datetime field.  I've seen functions which do this, but they don't seem to work with my data.

Date char(8): 20051101
TIME char(4): 1115

Result needed: Date time representing Nov. 1st 2005, 11:15 am

How can I do this?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the fields?

Comment: Added in question, please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data type is `int`, you can do:

```
declare @d as int
declare @t as int
set @d = 20051101
set @t = 1115
select CAST(cast(@d as varchar) as datetime) + dateadd(hh, cast(left(@t, 2) as int), 0) + dateadd(N, cast(right(@t, 2) as int), 0)
```

**Updated for char:**

```
declare @d as char(8)
declare @t as char(4)
set @d = '20051101'
set @t = '1115'
select CAST(@d as datetime) + dateadd(hh, cast(left(@t, 2) as int), 0) + dateadd(N, cast(right(@t, 2) as int), 0)
```